# UserControl calling JS-files but they don't seem to get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-controls, vb.net-2010

I have a usercontrol, which I created in VisualStudio2010.
It calls some js-files like this :

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SearchBox.ascx.vb" Inherits="NoVaCWWW.SearchBox" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl-BE.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/SearchPanel.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On a page where this usercontrol isn't used (and which calls the same scripts) everything works fine. This is: I have a date which is a jquery-ui-datepicker, and it works fine :

```
    <asp:Content ID="cntHeader" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderHeader">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SearchPanel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var fromDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', $("#<%= txtFromDate.ClientID %>").val());

                        $(".needs-datepicker").datepicker({
                                changeMonth: true,
                                changeYear: true,
                                dateFormat: '<%= Master.DateFormatJS %>',
                                altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                        });

                        //Map the hidden fields containing the same date but in a computer friendly format
                        $("#txtFromDateF").datepicker("option", "altField", "#<%= txtFromDate.ClientID %>");

                        //And make sure that dates are being shown in the visible fields
                        $("#txtFromDateF").datepicker('setDate', fromDate);
```

On a page that has the usercontrol, it doesn't work. I don't get a datepicker.
This is the usercontrol's script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/SearchPanel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(function () {
        $("#txtFromDateF").datepicker();
        $("#txtToDateF").datepicker();

        $(".needs-3mdatepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            maxDate: '+6m',
            minDate: '-3m'
        });

        $(".needs-datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            maxDate: '+6m'
        });

        $("#btnSearchCiNumber")
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: 'ui-icon-search'
                        },
                        label: $("#<%= SearchButton.ClientID %>").val()
                    })
                    .click(function () {
                        $("#<%= SearchButton.ClientID %>").click();
                    });
    });

    function btnSearchCiNumber_onclick() {

    }

    //-->
    </script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the files from the IIS-Server and then reinstalling the webapplication.
Now everything works fine.